# How to send concurrent requests in Jmeter

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, benchmarking

I want to use Jmeter to capture response times for requests to my web script in a concurrent way, but Jmeter sends them sequentially.  Is there any way I can simulate concurrent requests?

I'm looking for something similar to `web_concurrent_start()` in [LoadRunner](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-load-testing/overview).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JMeter provides [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) which can be used for kicking off all the requests in its scope at exactly the same moment.

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) guide for more information on where to place, how to use and existing limitations.

Comment: Synchronize timer works between 2 threads requirement is to sent multiple request same time which exsists within same thread

Comment: JMeter Thread group limitation doesn't allow to send more than one simultaneous request from one thread. However it can be worked around. See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for information on how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [TailSampler](https://github.com/pflb/Jmeter.Plugin.TailSampler) plugin - it simulates browser behavior by retrieving resources in a parallel way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try BlazeMeter
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter